# Pywinauto can`t find any windows() of started browser Application (Chrome or Firefox)

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, firefox, ui-automation, pywinauto

I can start with `pywinauto` chrome.exe or firefox.exe. They open Teb with needed URL properly, but i can't to apply to started window by "title" or "title_re", or some enother method - the app.windows() - is empty list!
I can see all windows by `inspect.exe`, i can see pywinauto.Desktop.windows() - all browser and other opened appplications in place.
But all attempts to apply browsers (both) rise error: `pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': '<some_name>', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 18024}`

Code

```py
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
import pyuac

class pywin(object):
    def __init__
...

    def Take_url(self):
...
    def Conn(self):
        app = Application(backend="uia").start(self.bro + self.Take_url())
#>>> self.bro + self.Take_url()
#"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility https://<mysite>" 

# And it really start, no problem

        #app = Application(backend="uia").start("calc.exe")
        process_ = app.process
        print(process_)
#process_
#>>> some integer PID 
        app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=process_)
#addition .connect does`t change anything, .windows() is empty yet, dump_tree() can't be taken, etc.
        time.sleep(10)
        print(app.windows())
>>> []
        app.kill() #Not work!


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        print("Re-launching as admin!")
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()

    go = pywin()
    go.Conn()
```

If i start some other application, for example 'calc.exe' - this code work absolute properly, i can see .dump_tree(), a can apply to app[u'Калькулятор'], i can finish it by .kill(). The problem only with browsers.
I tried this code on two different PC (Windows 7 & Windows 10) - not work for browsers. For empty browsers Window (with no URL in path) - it`s does't work too.

I have no ideas, pleese help!